# Detect USB Device Disconnection

Tags: android, usb, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to detect USB device disconnection. I'm using the code below:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "usb was disconneced",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

But it doesn't work. Nothing happens when I disconnect a USB storage. What is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive power connected or disconnected events, like this by placing it in the android manifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and further more about details explanation about USB connect and disconnect follow the [example](http://androidforbeginner.blogspot.in/2012/09/detect-usb-connection-in-android.html)

Comment: I tried the example before. It didn't work. I'll give your "ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" suggestion a chance.